# Задать параметры ввода для экранной клавиатуры android

Tags: android, клавиатура

Интересует реализация следующих функций экранной клавиатуры:

1 программно спрятать клавиатуру после нажатия на imageView

2 назначить собственное "действие" на кнопку клавиатуры "ввод"/"далее"

3 отобразить на клавиатуре кнопку "лупа"

Спасибо за участие.

Answer (score 0):

> программно спрятать клавиатуру после нажатия на imageView

а если требуется прятать после нажатия `Button` или `ImageButton` - как это связано именно с `ImageView`?!

> назначить собственное "действие" на кнопку клавиатуры "ввод"/"далее"

Документацию читать не пробовали? [RTFM](https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/style.html)

> отобразить на клавиатуре кнопку "лупа"

```
android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
```

P.S. Вообще такие вопросы оскорбляют до глубины души...

Comment: Не отбивайте охоту пользоваться сервисом. И спасибо за помощ

Comment: Задавайте вопросы почетче, без потока сознания - и будет вам счастье.